# install magento2 on xampp

Tags: magento2, php-7, xampp

I am trying to install magento2 on xampp server and get these errors:
these PHP extensios are not available:

PHP Extension xsl.
PHP Extension intl.
PHP Extension soap.

Please tell me how to remove these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error you are getting is quite common** with beginners during magento 2 installation. It is better to follow this [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html). The error you are seeing in your installation process means that **your server lacks php xsl,intl and soap extension.** **You must install** these according to your php version. To check the php extensions installed in your server use this command in terminal.

```
php -m
```

To enable your intl extension you must locate your **`php.ini`** file and uncomment this line: **`;extension=php_intl.dll`** by **removing semicolon at the beginning.**

Similarly for other two extensions uncomment .i.e remove semi-colon at the beginning.

**`;extension=php_xsl.dll`**

**`;extension=php_soap.dll`**

To see it's effect you need to **restart your xampp server**.

**If you do not know where your `php.ini` file is located then**:

For **Windows**, you can find the file in the **C:\xampp\php\php.ini**-Folder (Windows) **or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder)**.

Under **Linux**, most distributions put lampp under **/opt/lampp**, so the file can be found under **/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini.**

Comment: its not working. i removed the "!".

Comment: did you restart your xamp server? Make sure you have those modules enabled or installed by using command php -m

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

These
PHP Extension xsl. PHP Extension intl. PHP Extension soap.
extensions are by default disabled in php configuration file (php.ini)

To install magento2, we need to enable these extensions: To do this in Windows:-
Go to **C:\xampp\php\php.ini** edit this php.ini file in the text editior and
**remove the semicolon at the beginning** of following lines:

;extension=php_intl.dll

;extension=php_soap.dll

;extension=php_xsl.dll

If the above lines are not available in php.ini file then below lines must be available

;extension=intl

;extension=soap

;extension=xsl

**Remove the semicolon at the beginning of these lines** and **Save the php.ini file, stop and start Apache again**

Cheers !!

Thank You !!